# The include, bin, and lib directories for cygwin gcc/g++ compilers

Tags: gcc, include, cygwin, bin

I'm trying to install a programming library onto Cygwin, and I have all the things I need except that I don't know where to put the include, bin, and lib files that the library uses. I've tried looking in the help that Cygwin provides but can't find the directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which compiler you are using. If you are using the standard "gcc4" Cygwin compiler, then the directories are simply

```
/usr/bin # C:\cygwin\bin
/usr/lib # C:\cygwin\lib
/usr/include # C:\cygwin\usr\include
```

If you are using other compiler, it will be different.

```
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include
```